PBI Desktop Direct query - How to countrows
I'm in PBI Desktop; connected via direct query and trying to count the number of occurrence of a specified column; to use it then in column to be able to use it as slicer
Long story short; I've project ID; parent ID, and wish to know for each code if there is "children" (like P1.1) or not; if there is, they will be reporting on the children, if not, on the parent (reporting is the column to be used as slicer then).
I would like to be able to create the two "yellow" columns.

I try already to create a new table getting the number by parent id; but can't use it in the main table then as related not working.

Is the parent for P3.1 is P3?
maybe you can try this
Column = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('Table'),ALLEXCEPT('Table','Table'[parent]))

Column 2 = if('Table'[projectname]='Table'[parent],"no","yes")


